# Gtk2: event for top menu item click?

Tags: gtk2

I want to see how to make it in Gtk2 (e.g. C++). Does gtk2 has ability to set event which is called, when top menu item is clicked?
E.g. topmenu may be "File Edit Help". When "Edit" clicked (Alt+E key too) I want that event is called (event sets checkmarks for menu items in Edit).

How to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "trap" them with [activate-current](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuShell.html#GtkMenuShell-activate-current). As most of the widgets, they have an activated signal handler.

Comment: It is for Gtk3, but what is info on Gtk2, please?

Comment: Did you search for the same therm in gtk2 documentation? Please just don't downvote or unanswer without confirmation, that's not good.